# Grafana Prometheus - query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to get my query to sum over intervals in grafana but I get this error:

```
"query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution"
```

if I look at the last 30days at a daily interval.

I have a variable called `intrvl` with certain time intervals like `1m, 1h, 12h, 24h, and 30d`, and my query looks like this:

```
sort_desc(
sum by (backend)(sum_over_time(haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{code=~"[1,2,3,4][x][x]",tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]))
/
sum by (backend)(sum_over_time(haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{code!~"\\b(\\w*other\\w*)\\b",tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]))
)
```

I'm using a line chart viz and I also have `Min step` of the chart set to `$intrvl` as well. Is this the right way to calculate a percentage based on a time range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**too many samples** error message comes from Prometheus (`promql/engine.go`), not Grafana. [issue #4513](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/4513)

You can try to raise the limit with Prometheus flag `--query.max-samples` introduced in Prometheus v2.5.0. (see default for your version in `prometheus -h` output).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a considered amount of data to calculate your formula, I would consider creating a [prometheus recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/), that will pre compute the values needed and 
 `sum_over_interval`using the created rule.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:** performing massive query in prometheus throws an error in Grafana dashboard and fail the result:

```
query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution
```

**Solution:** Use `--query.max-samples` in prometheus configuration file and increase the number of load in memory. default value is `50000000` , increase this value depends on your machine capabilities. From **[documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/prometheus/prometheus.1.en.html)**:

```
--query.max-samples=50000000
     Maximum number of samples a single query can load into memory. 
     Note that queries will fail if they try to load more samples than this into memory,
     so this also limits the number of samples a query can return.
```

**Example:** Assuming you run your prometheus service in docker-compose execution
on `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

services:   
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--query.max-samples=100000000'
      - '--web.external-url=http://prom.some-company-url.com:9090'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `haproxy_backend_http_responses_total` metric is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), so it is likely [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function must be used instead of [sum_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time):

```
sort_desc(
sum by (backend)(increase(haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{code=~"[1234]..",tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]))
/
sum by (backend)(increase(haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]))
)
```

- The `sum_over_time()` function calculates the sum of all the raw samples on the given lookbehind window in square brackets. This function is intended for [gauges](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge).
- The `increase()` function calculates the increase of a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) over the given lookbehind window.

The `too many samples` error occurs because Prometheus loads into memory all the raw samples for all the time series matching the given [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) on the given lookbehind window specified in square brackets. It is likely the `haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{tags=~".*external.*"}` selector matches big number of time series. The following query can be used for estimating the number of time series the query needs to load into memory:

```
count(
  last_over_time(
    haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]
  )
)
```

The following query can be used for estimating the number of raw sample the query needs to load into memory:

```
sum(
  count_over_time(
    haproxy_backend_http_responses_total{tags=~".*external.*"}[$intrvl]
  )
)
```

As you can see, the number of matching time series and the number of raw samples, which Prometheus needs to load into memory, grows with the lookbehind window in square brackets - `[$intrvl]` in queries above.

[This article](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-optimize-promql-and-metricsql-queries-85a1b75bf986) may be useful for understanding how to determine the root cause for heavy PromQL queries and how to optimize them.

The `too many samples` error may be fixed by passing bigger value to `--query.max-samples` command-line flag as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454482/274937). Note that this may increase memory usage when Prometheus processes heavy queries.

An alternative solution for fixing the `too many samples` error is to use other Prometheus-like systems, which may need lower amounts of memory when processing heavy queries. Try, for example, [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).